# insert elements while iterating a sorted stl container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I found unexpected result while my code insert element into std::set while iterating it. I need enlightenment on it.

Here is the test code:

```
    template<class Ti, class T>
    void iteration_insertion(Ti start, Ti end, T& S){
        for (auto ite=start;ite!=end;++ite){
            auto before=*ite;
            if(*ite % 2)
                S.insert(*ite*2);
            else
                S.insert(*ite/2);
            if(before!=*ite)
                cout<<before<<","<<*ite<<endl;
        }
    }
    void test() {
        set<int> S1({4,7,10,13}),S2(S1);
        cout<<"ascending\n";
        iteration_insertion(S1.begin(),S1.end(),S1);
        cout<<"descending\n";
        iteration_insertion(S2.rbegin(),S2.rend(),S2);
    }
```

and the result:

```
ascending
descending
13,26
```

As we can see the element where iterator points to is changed after insertion, sometimes. But I can't tell when it would happen. In the test code it only happened once, for 13 in descending. Why there is no such mismatch in the ascending iteration? Why there is no mismatch for 7 in descending iteration?  How to prevent it from happening? I'm fine with the new added value could be iterated later, which is expected. I just don't want the iterator changed by insertion.

The test code can be a generic heuristic practice: from each current state generating new states for further check.

Comment: Thanks to the answers by @chris, I guess the easiest solution is not to use reversed iterator, but use forward with std::greater as comparer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to account for all elements of the container, a reverse iterator stores the iterator for the element past the one you get when you dereference it. For example, the result of `rbegin()` internally stores a one-past-the-end iterator. When you dereference, a copy of the stored iterator is made and that copy is decremented before it is dereferenced.

Essentially, a simplified version of the standard code used:

```
template<typename Iter>
struct reverse_iterator {
    Iter base;

    auto& operator++() { --base; return *this; }
    auto& operator*() {
        auto copy = base;
        --copy;
        return *copy;
    }
};

auto std::set::rbegin() {
    return reverse_iterator{this->end()};
}
```

Applying this to your situation, you start with `rbegin()`. Dereferencing this gives you the last element, 13. When you insert 26, it is inserted after 13, but before the one-past-the-end iterator that is stored internally within `ite`. When you dereference `ite` again, a copy of the internal one-past-the-end iterator is made and that is decremented to the position between 13 and 26, then dereferenced to give 26.

Here is the picture version of the explanation in case that helps:

[image: diagram showing ite's internal iterator]

Comment: For forward iterator (start with begin()), or for reverse iterator but not pointing to the rbegin( ), would there be such mismatch after insertion?

Comment: @jerron, Not for a forward iterator because you can think of the iterator as being attached to the element following the split where it "points to". For `std::set`, the iterator's going to have some kind of pointer to the node in the tree containing the element and an insertion won't change what's in an already-existing node. For a reverse iterator, this will happen any time an element is inserted immediately following the current one in the unreversed set because the internal iterator is attached to the node following the "current" one instead of this one directly.

Comment: @jerron, You can [see an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5uIQrv3TlHZSag3A) of what I mean. The base iterator is unchanged, but the current element changes with insertion because there's a new element before the base iterator. It's also worth pointing out that from the perspective of the standard, the forward case is covered by iterator invalidation guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

A [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

> contains a sorted set

of values. Emphasis on the "sorted" part. Inserting a new value into the set [does not invalidate any existing iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert), so inserting is valid, on its own merits.

However, because the container ***always*** contains a "sorted" set, if the newly inserted value is greater than the one your iterator is referencing, and you advance the iterator forward, at some point you will iterate over the new value, because it is now a part of the set, which must always be in sorted order.

If the new value is less than your iterator's currently referenced value, advancing the iterator forward will not iterate over the new value, by definition.

There is no way to "prevent it from happening" because this is how `std::set`s work, by definition. You will need to "prevent it from happening" all by yourself. Perhaps by inserting any new values into a separate `std::vector`, and after you're done iterating you then insert the accumulated new values, from that vector, into your set.

Comment: But why no such behavior in the "ascending" part of the code? With "4", we are inserting a "2", just like what we do with "13" in the deceding code. Also, why no mismatch for "7" in decending?